# Coming from web development, how should I think about VB.net app architecture?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have inherited a vb.net app at work, and I'm doing some work on it. The entire app is essentially five thousand lines of function calls. I'd like to clean it up as I work on it.

I come from a web background, and tend to think of application architecture in terms of the MVC paradigm. I am having trouble understanding the right way to think about this app. For example:

1. I'd like to separate the model layer out from the data manipulation & GUI logic. Currently there are WinForms components being used like DataGridView, which from my understanding lets the user essentially update the data directly. Should I not have a separate model layer like I'm used to having? My instinct would be to make a separate class for each database table, have those classes interface with the database, then have the GUI retrieve the data by instantiating/acting on those classes. Do WinForms components obviate the need for this type of architecture?
2. I'm confused about how to organize some of the auto-generated code from the designer. For example, in my web apps, I would have a View object for each piece of the UI, which would be responsible for rendering and event handling. In the current code, event handlers are basically just functions in the single giant class. Should I think about this the same way? Meaning, as I refactor, I will have separate classes for the UI pieces, and I'll be able to write the event handlers there? I don't actually know where all the rendering code lives. Do I ever even have to worry about that code?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, as well as any resources that could help me understand how to better structure the code.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to worry about the generated designer code. Usually.

I have found the most comprehensible and testable way to design a WinForms application is as you indicate - similar to what you would do in web programming.

Essentially you have three(ish) types of classes:

1. The View layer. This is anything that inherits from `Windows.Forms.*` This layer should be relatively stupid. If you'd like to put the display logic in this layer it's certainly possible and a legitimate use, but for maximum testability you could go with the [Passive View](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PassiveScreen.html), where the view *only* raises events, and all of the properties are set from the presenter
2. Presentation layer. This layer decides *how* the data should be presented - which view, and if you're using the Passive View pattern then it also decides things like colors, visibiltiy, enabled, etc. This layer can do validation, etc. etc.
3. Model layer. This is where your business logic goes - basically your entire business process should be able to be represented in relationships between models. The presentation layer is for coordinating between the models and the user (via the view) and the data stores (which technically could be considered models, of sorts).

There are other patterns, but this is the one that I find most natural and allows you to write the simplest code possible.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense to me. Is it relatively straight-forward with things like DataGridViews? I should still be able to control where the data comes from, do business logic/validation before the data is shown/persisted, etc.?

Comment: Yeah, and the way I prefer to do it is actually do something like `view.DataSource = myData` - I've only had problems with funny things when doing data binding.

Answer (score 1):

1) having a `DAL` is a great idea. `Entity Framework` creates strongly typed classes of your tables with the fields as properties. The constraints and relationships still exist as well.

2) you don't have to mess with the designer generated code files as they take care of themselves. I don't think you need a class for each `UI` component - unless we are talking about Usercontrols or sub-classed controls.

Comment: Regarding #2: in web, if I had a todo app, and the user clicked 'Add todo', I would send the event to an 'addTodo' handler, perhaps on a controller somewhere. In the vb.net app, previous devs typically just double-clicked the buttons and used the generated code. So (1) could I change the location of these functions, and move them to different classes? and (2) where is the proper place for these functions, if there is no separate class that represents the UI component?

Comment: And thanks! I'll have to check out the Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

On #1, I've treated VB apps with a model/view pattern since VB4 days. Unfortunately, few classic VB'ers did it this way and this tendency carried over to VB.NET. Therefore, you can end up with messy apps that mix UI and database calls extensively. How much you can refactor this depends on the app. In some cases, it's easy to extract the model and build a data access layer but in others, the app is to brittle to move anything.

As DonA mentioned, the Entity Framework is an easy way to create strongly typed classes. The only drawback I've found with this method is working with a lot of pre-existing stored procedures. In this situation I used a simplified DAL of my own design that fed objects. You can also use Entity Framework to directly call procs and load objects if you have a mixture of direct table and SPs.

On #2, you shouldn't need to change the generated code in most cases. I'd leave it as is unless there's a compelling reason to change it manually. One way to think of it would be that the generated code is your View and the code behind is kind of the Controller.

One thing you can do to make the code more DRY is to consolidate validations and such since you can easily assign more than one UI object event to a single method. Often you'll see repetitive code in VB event processing. Consolidation can go a long way to making VB WinForms code more manageable.